# Create a 2 dimensional item source for list in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, tile

I an looking to create a tile display in XAML where the tile has an text and a color.

The way our UI framework is designed, UI developers dont have access to code behind but we can create controls that can bind to primitive values (integer, boolean, double,String etc) or a list of strings.

So I am looking for a solution where I use 2 list of string (binded to a list box) and then use the items for those two list boxes to create a tile view.

Creating a tiled view from a single list box is doable but I cant seem to figure out how to bind to another list to control the color of the tile.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you have to write a `IValueConverter` or `AttachedProperty`.

Comment: Why do You have 2 lists? build one list with object that contains both values you need per Tile.